# awk processing filenames with special characters in *system call*

Tags: awk, special-characters, system

I am processing a large list of `md5, dir/filename` pairs. I need to insert the file size into the list to make `md5, size, dir/filename` 3-tuple list.

The relevant snippet of the data file is:

```
file MD5sum-stage1A.txt
...
d9c6be18d35619c7532f9c94f5a9bf58  /mnt/dir1/dir2/branch1/04 05 Custom .mp4
01c0fadb91c8ef0815a7753ad25a8c1c  /mnt/dir1/dir2/branch1/branch2/Using the -proc directory and the $$ Variable.odt
...
EOF
```

The 2nd data line is the problem, with the `$$` in the filename.

The code is working, except so far, for the one exception.
the following is the code thus far:

```
someone@system01:~/tmp$ awk 'NR==15522, NR==15523 {
> md5=$1
> file=substr($0,35)
> size="###"
> cmd=sprintf("stat --format=%s \"%s\"", "%s",file)
> cmd | getline size
> close(cmd)
> printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",md5, size, file
> }' MD5sum-stage1A.txt

d9c6be18d35619c7532f9c94f5a9bf58    6747587 /mnt/dir1/dir2/dir3/04 05 Custom .mp4
stat: cannot stat '/mnt/dir1/dir2/Using the -proc directory and the 20483 Variable.odt': No such file or directory
01c0fadb91c8ef0815a7753ad25a8c1c    ### /mnt/dir1/dir2/Using the -proc directory and the $$ Variable.odt
```

So far the code is handling the nuances of the shell and handling spaces and most characters in a filename.
However, the shell appears to be wanting to substitute the '$$' with the processid.

With **Awk** how can this behaviour be mitigated?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't leave people guessing about your question. Mention sample input and expected sample output in code tags(with all details and logic how you want to achieve it) in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Originally, yes. The output of a file system comparison script.

Comment: As for inputs and outputs; they are already there.

Comment: My first inclination would be to use perl or another language that doesn't require invoking a shell to get a file's size.

Comment: I'm starting to be inclined to agree, however; I find perl rather terse and thus tend to have used python a little.

 Does anyone have any suggestions on doing the same in python?

Comment: To do it in awk you would probably have to write `printf  "%q"` implementation in awk and quote the string, something along `gsub("$", "\$", "g", file)`

Comment: If you have `gawk`, it has an extension called `filefuncs` which provides a `stat` function. You can get a file's size using it like `gawk -lfilefuncs 'BEGIN{stat("filename",buf); print buf["size"]}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the answers, they gave me a few ideas and hopefully streamline and optimised the initial task. So in the spirit of sharing what I ended up with and maybe it will be of use to someone else, is:

```
find /media/BACKUPS/foo -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -exec md5sum {} \; -printf '%s\n' | awk 'NF==1{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",hash,$1,rest;next}{hash=$1;rest=substr($0,index($0,$2))}'  >  MD5sum-dataset-foo.txt
```

and again, Many Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to generate the MD5 and the size of the file together.

For example using `find` to locate file and `awk` to format the output:

```
find /mypath -type f -exec md5sum {} \; -exec stat -c %s {} \; | \
  awk  'NF==1{print hash,$1,rest;next}{hash=$1;rest=substr($0,35)}'
```

If you can't generate the MD5 and need to re-use the file, you can avoid `awk` and do it with bash `read` command:

```
while read hash f; do 
   echo "$hash $(stat -c %s "$f") $f"
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like such: use xargs to read one line at a time and then split the line using `cut -d" "` to cut the parts of the input:

```
xargs -n1 -d $'\n' bash -c 'f=$(cut -d" " -f3- <<<"$1"); printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$(cut -d" " -f1 <<<"$1")" "$(stat -c %s "$f")" "$f"' --
```

Or substitute the double spaces and newlines for some unreadable character (like 0x01 byte) that you can easily handle:

```
sed 's/  /\x01/' | tr '\n' '\01' |
xargs -n2 -d $'\x01' bash -c 'printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$1" "$(stat -c %s "$2")" "$2"' --
```

or even substitute the double spaces for some unreadable character:

```
sed 's/  /\x01/' |
while IFS=$'\x01' read -r md5 file; do
     printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t\n" "$md5" "$(stat -c %s "$file")" "$file" 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't calling stat from awk with the same quoting you'd use when calling stat from shell - if you call stat from shell with the same quoting as you're using in the awk command you'd get the same error. Look:

```
$ ls
'foo $$ bar'

$ stat --format=%s "foo $$ bar"
stat: cannot stat 'foo 1913 bar': No such file or directory
```

and now with correct quoting:

```
$ stat --format='%s' 'foo $$ bar'
6
```

In your awk command you're currently using incorrect quoting:

```
awk -v file='foo $$ bar' 'BEGIN{cmd=sprintf("stat --format=%s \"%s\"", "%s",file); cmd | getline size; close(cmd); print file, size}'
stat: cannot stat 'foo 2523 bar': No such file or directory
foo $$ bar
```

but if you used the same quoting as in the correctly quoted shell command:

```
awk -v file='foo $$ bar' 'BEGIN{cmd=sprintf("stat --format=\047%s\047 \047%s\047", "%s",file); cmd | getline size; close(cmd); print file, size}'
foo $$ bar 6
```

You can print a literal `%` in a formatting string by just doubling it up btw:

```
awk -v file='foo $$ bar' 'BEGIN{cmd=sprintf("stat --format=\047%%s\047 \047%s\047",file); cmd | getline size; close(cmd); print file, size}'
foo $$ bar 6
```

Here's how I'd really approach this though:

```
$ ls -1
'an other file'
files
'foo $$ bar'

$ cat files
12345   an other file
987     foo $$ bar

$ cut -f2- files | xargs -d'\n' stat --format='%s'
5
6

$ cut -f2- files | xargs -d'\n' stat --format='%s' |
    awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{size[NR]=$0; next} {print size[FNR], $0}' - files
5       12345   an other file
6       987     foo $$ bar
```